# pandas DataFrame filter regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, filter

I don't understand `pandas` `DataFrame` `filter`.

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['Hello', 'World'],
        ['Just', 'Wanted'],
        ['To', 'Say'],
        ['I\'m', 'Tired']
    ]
)
```

#### Problem

```
df.filter([0], regex=r'(Hel|Just)', axis=0)
```

I'd expect the `[0]` to specify the 1st column as the one to look at and `axis=0` to specify filtering rows.  What I get is this:

```
       0      1
0  Hello  World
```

I was expecting

```
       0       1
0  Hello   World
1   Just  Wanted
```

#### Question

- What would have gotten me what I expected?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html),

> Arguments are mutually exclusive, but this is not checked for

So, it appears, the first optional argument, `items=[0]` trumps the third optional argument, `regex=r'(Hel|Just)'`.

```
In [194]: df.filter([0], regex=r'(Hel|Just)', axis=0)
Out[194]: 
       0      1
0  Hello  World
```

is equivalent to

```
In [201]: df.filter([0], axis=0)
Out[201]: 
       0      1
0  Hello  World
```

which is merely selecting the row(s) with index values in `[0]` along the 0-axis.

---

To get the desired result, you could use `str.contains` to create a boolean mask,
and use `df.loc` to select rows:

```
In [210]: df.loc[df.iloc[:,0].str.contains(r'(Hel|Just)')]
Out[210]: 
       0       1
0  Hello   World
1   Just  Wanted
```

Answer (score 12):

This should work:

`df[df[0].str.contains('(Hel|Just)', regex=True)]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a chaining method:

```
df.loc[lambda x: x['column_name'].str.contains(regex_patern, regex = True)]
```